# is there a difference between these 3 diodes?

Tags: diodes, schottky, buying

http://www.mouser.fr/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=1N5819-E3/73

- 1N5819-E3/73
- 1N5819-E3/53
- 1N5819-E3/54

the first one is 4x cheaper than the last, why ?

aren't they all the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and last are actually exactly the same price (0,092 €) if you buy the full package.

Looks to me like a packaging difference. The first is presumably cut tape from an ammo pack bandolier and the last is cut tape (Bande coupée) from a reel.

Tape and Reel:

[image: http://www.kingtronics.cn/upload/08124.jpg]

Ammo Pack:

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rE-3MGtfLho/TbmFdHQJ0MI/AAAAAAAAABE/8iPPOVRf3o8/s200/ammo.jpg]

The ammo pack is similar to the reel, but Z-folded and put into a box (the name comes from the similarity in appearance to bandoliers of ammunition for automatic weapons).

Electrically, and physically, once you get them off the tape, they're same part. They would also be similar in cut tape form, but the ammo pack would have some kinks in the tape every so many (maybe few hundred) parts.

As to why they're priced differently in small quantities- the distributor probably wants to discourage hacking bits off the reels and making them unsalable to those who want to buy an entire reel.